# Optimal structure of grouped products with more than 30K unique products

Tags: grouped-products, catalog-optimize

I have a question to community how to organize my catalog with grouped products. Following my situation:

```
1. I have more than 30K unique simple products (not visible in catalog). 
2. I have more than 5K grouped products (visible in catalog)
3. Every grouped product contains of combination of simple products on point 1.
4. One simple product can be included to 1-5 grouped product.
```

That is not to hard to organize my catalog, but problem is:

Product "SA" is child product for "GA", "GB", "GD". And "SA" has unique value for every group, for example polygon, order, image attributes are differentiated for every parent group. But it is one simple product with unique sku and price. In the catalog there are many such products given like this.

If the situation is clear can you help me how to organize simple and grouped products. Thanks.

### Updated

Products comes in .csv file and I should write custom module to organize products. One variant is to save every unique combination as new product and link them to group product appropriately. For example if "SA" product has 3 parent product I will save "SA" as 3 new product and so on. By the way if I have 30K unique products in .csv file the result of import will produce more than 80K products in magento db. And database size will overloaded. Currently I haven't another optimal way.

Comment: Did you already try something or have some possible solutions in mind?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you want a way to import these products into some kind of new / specific attribute set?
Or do you want to order them in some way in the backend. Please provide more info

Comment: I want to import these products to Magento store, but how can I organize the structure of grouped products with given condition above. These products are given in .csv file, I know to import pro grammatically, but have any optimal structure for my condition.

Answer (score -1):

Magento products have attributes, but their values are set only for cart items (quote items). That means you can not apply different values for different groups for the same product.

When configurable product is created it is used as template to create simple products for every combination of options. Thus inventory and all other stuff is related to corresponding simple product.

So, just as you wrote, different simple products are needed for all groups. And you will have big number of products.

Comment: If one simple product is added to cart from 2 different grouped product then they will be calculated as 2 different quote items, but they are one exact products.

Comment: As I can understand from your description, you want to have different values of some product attributes for every group. But simple product doesn't have changeable attributes, it possess only their values. Grouped product contains simple product with its values for attributes (not attributes, but specific values). Hence no changes are possible. Configurable products contain changeable attributes though. But for every set of values you have to add simple product (with specific values and not attributes). So _"SA" has unique value for every group_ means every group has unique product.